# How to make a JFrame have no taskbar button?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, taskbar

I would like to have a normal JFrame with its full functionalities (decoration, title, icon, resizing, minimizing, maximizing, etc.), with the only thing that it wouldn't appear in the system's taskbar.

(Typically, there would be another program opening and managing them).

Is it possible ? And if yes, what is the best way to do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a non-modal `JDialog` instead of a `JFrame`.

Comment: I'm not sure if I can do same with a JDialog, though. If I remember, I can't set a specific icon, or have the minimize and maximize buttons.